# Are there exceptions that don't stop script's execution?

Tags: php, exception

I've written error handling class which divided all errors into the normal ones (notices, warnings, ...), and the critical ones.

Now I've found out that it's a good practice to convert all errors into exceptions. It would also shorten my code.

However, I'm not sure how to handle this...

1. Are there exceptions that don't stop scripts execution, and exceptions that do? If there aren't...how to differ converted errors?
2. Converting errors into exception is done by calling set_error_handler() and throw new ErrorException() in there...What's next? set_exception_handler() is called automagically?

Comment: `Are there exceptions that don't stop scripts execution` did you mean to say errors instead of exceptions?

Comment: No, I understand converting errors to exceptions this way: converting notice/warning gives an exception that doesn't stop script. Converting errors/fatal errors gives exceptions that stop scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Are there exceptions that don't stop scripts execution, and exceptions that do? If there aren't...how to differ converted errors?

Exceptions don't stop script execution if they're caught. To recognize a converted error:

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (ErrorException $e) {
    // converted error (probably)
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // another kind of exception; this basically catches all
}
```

Or:

```
function handle_exception(Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof ErrorException) {
        // converted error (probably)
    } else {
        // another kind of exception
    }
}
set_exception_handler('handle_exception');
```

*Note that `ErrorException` can be thrown by any piece of code, but it was meant to convert regular errors in `set_error_handler()` registered functions only.*

> 1. Converting errors into exception is done by calling set_error_handler() and throw new ErrorException() in there...What's next? set_exception_handler() is called automagically?

If the thrown `ErrorException` from your error handler function is not caught anywhere else in your code, the registered exception handler (set using `set_exception_handler()`) will be called.

Answer (score 3):

1. Caught exceptions do not stop your script, **all uncaught ones do**.
2. No, [**`set_exception_handler()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) is not called automatically, you *can* do that if you like.

   The exception handler you set with `set_exception_handler()` gets called after an exception has gone uncaught, it is the *last piece of code* that gets called before the script terminates. Make sure it doesn't cause an error/exception, or it will end badly.

Answer (score 2):

Any uncaught exception will stop execution of your script.

> When an exception is thrown, code following the statement will not be
>   executed, and PHP will attempt to find the first matching catch block.
>   **If an exception is not caught, a PHP Fatal Error will be issued** with
>   an "Uncaught Exception ..." message, unless a handler has been defined
>   with set_exception_handler().

See [docs about this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

As for `set_exception_handler()` - it is not called automatically, but it is your last resort to react to the problem that occured

> Sets the default exception handler if an exception is not caught
>   within a try/catch block. Execution will stop after the
>   exception_handler is called.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you can only convert *Warnings* into Exceptions, errors cannot be converted to Exceptions because the error handler doesn't run.

```
set_error_handler(function ($severity, $message, $file, $line) {
  echo 'You will never see this.'
});

// Provoke an error
function_that_does_not_exist();
```

It is possible to "catch" them using a shutdown function, but that is out of the scope of the question.

Comment: It will trigger the error handler if the problematic code is in an included file, which is usually the case.